# Rapid calls to fread crashes the application

Tags: c++, audio, wav, fread

I'm writing a function to load a wave file and, in the process, split the data into 2 separate buffers if it's stereo. The program gets to i = 18 and crashes during the left channel fread pass. (You can ignore the couts, they are just there for debugging.) Maybe I should load the file in one pass and use memmove to fill the buffers?

```
if(params.channels == 2){
    params.leftChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize/2];
    params.rightChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize/2];

    bool isLeft = true;

    int offset = 0;
    const int stride = sizeof(BYTE) * (params.bitsPerSample/8);

    for(int i = 0; i < params.dataSize; i += stride)
    {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << " ";
        if(isLeft){
            std::cout << "Before Left Channel, ";
            fread(params.leftChannelData+offset, sizeof(BYTE), stride, file + i);
            std::cout << "After Left Channel, ";
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Before Right Channel, ";
            fread(params.rightChannelData+offset, sizeof(BYTE), stride, file + i);
            std::cout << "After Right Channel, ";
            offset += stride;
            std::cout << "After offset incr.\n";
        }

        isLeft != isLeft;
    }

} else {
    params.leftChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize];
    fread(params.leftChannelData, sizeof(BYTE), params.dataSize, file);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong to me: `file + i`

You've just got one file handle, right?  Don't add `i` to it!!

> file is a FILE* My assumption was, like most pointers, that adding an
>   integer to the pointer would read from an offset in the file.

FILE* is a pointer to a FILE structure that stores information about the file you have open.  You always pass that pointer to stdio functions.  If you want to seek to a specific position in the file, use `fseek`.  If you are just reading the file sequentially from start to end, you do not need to seek.

Comment: file is a FILE* 

My assumption was, like most pointers, that adding an integer to the pointer would read from an offset in the file. Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: Yep, that assumption is wrong.  I have edited my answer to explain.

Comment: @Slynk `FILE *` is not a pointer to data in the file... if you want to seek to a certain position, use `fseek` (or `fsetpos` depending on the context)

Comment: Thanks. That works (though I need to speed up my solution which is an entirely different story.) You answered my question so fast that I can't mark it as my accepted answer for another 2 minutes. XD

Comment: Hehe no worries.  Hope you had time to make a coffee =)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who want's my complete solution, I'm posting this. Turns out cycling between fread calls is much slower than one fread call with cycling between memcpy calls (though it takes twice the memory). Another issue in my posted code was that I said:

```
isLeft != isLeft;
```

instead of

```
isLeft = !isLeft;
```

Solution:

```
if(params.channels == 2){
    params.leftChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize/2];
    params.rightChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize/2];
    unsigned char * buf = new unsigned char[params.dataSize];

    fread(buf, sizeof(BYTE), params.dataSize, file);

    bool isLeft = true;

    int offset = 0;
    const int stride = params.bitsPerSample/8;

    for(int i = 0; i < params.dataSize; i += stride)
    {

        if(isLeft)
            memcpy(&params.leftChannelData[offset], &buf[i], stride * sizeof(BYTE));
        else{
            memcpy(&params.rightChannelData[offset], &buf[i], stride * sizeof(BYTE));
            offset += stride;
        }
        isLeft = !isLeft;
    }

    params.dataSize = params.dataSize/2;

    delete(buf);

} else {
    params.leftChannelData = new unsigned char[params.dataSize];
    params.rightChannelData = NULL;
    fread(params.leftChannelData, sizeof(BYTE), params.dataSize, file);
}
```